# What is #bags,#messages?

Tags: php, laravel

When I am doing server side validation I am dumping the `$errors` array. Can you explain this array format? What does the `#` tag mean?

```
ViewErrorBag {#135 ▼
  #bags: array:1 [▼
    "default" => MessageBag {#136 ▼
      #messages: array:5 [▼
        "fullname" => array:1 [▼
          0 => "The fullname field is required."
        ]
        "email" => array:1 [▼
          0 => "The email field is required."
        ]
        "username" => array:1 [▼
          0 => "The username field is required."
        ]
        "password" => array:1 [▼
          0 => "The password field is required."
        ]
        "gender" => array:1 [▼
          0 => "The gender field is required."
        ]
      ]
      #format: ":message"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It's just a class for storing groups of messages. https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Contracts/Support/MessageBag.html

Answer (score 0):

ViewErrorBag is an array of MessageBags, that is all. # bags is just referencing the array